# Plot on command within DynamicModule?

Tags: performance-tuning, dynamic

Suppose I have a `DynamicModule` with all sorts of controls to set some parameters for a graphics object.

```
DynamicModule[{a = 0, b = 0},
  Column[{
    Slider[Dynamic[a]],
    Slider[Dynamic[b]],
    Dynamic[Plot[Sin[(a + 1) t + \[Pi] b], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
  }]
]
```

This graph is updated every time one of the dynamic parameters change.  Now pretend my graphics is a really slow 3D plot.  How can I construct it so that it only renders the graphic when I tell it to?  A button?  A mouse event?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the user to have absolute control over updates...say, by having an explicit Update button, then you can do so by adding an independent variable to control the updating and changing your `Dynamic` so that it only tracks that variable. Here, I introduce a variable `update`, which is an integer. Its value and type don't matter...what matter is that the `Dynamic` only updates when that variable does:

```
DynamicModule[{a = 0, b = 0, update = 0}, 
 Column[{Slider[Dynamic[a]], Slider[Dynamic[b]], 
   Button["Update", update++], 
   Dynamic[update; Plot[Sin[(a + 1) t + \[Pi] b], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
    TrackedSymbols :> {update}]}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the following solves your problem. The option that you look  for is `ContinuousAction -> False`. If you use Manipulate then using the same option you will get your requested update button. In the following once you decide where you want to locate your slider then only the computation will be initiated not continuously during the instantaneous slider movement

```
DynamicModule[{a = 0, b = 0}, 
Column[{Slider[Dynamic[a], {-3, 3, .01}, ContinuousAction -> False], 
Slider[Dynamic[b], {-3, 3, .01}, ContinuousAction -> False], 
Dynamic[Plot3D[Sin[a x + y^2 b], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotPoints -> 140, Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
ImageSize -> 400]], 
Dynamic["Time Count: " <> ToString@Clock[4]]}, 
Frame -> All]]
```

[image]

I used some options for Plot3D to generate a bit heavy graphics and also gave a reference clock cycle of four seconds to sense the computation time after the control triggers are decided.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ContinuousAction -> False` is a good suggestion, and the simplest solution.  If you'd prefer to get some real time feedback even during dragging the slider, you can use `ControlActive` to temporarily change the value of parameters that affect performance.

```
DynamicModule[{a = 0, b = 0},
 Column[
  {Slider[Dynamic[a]], Slider[Dynamic[b]],
   Dynamic[
    Plot3D[Sin[a x + b/y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2},
     PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 100],
     MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[0, 3],
     Mesh -> None,
     ImageSize -> 400]]
   }]]
```

This is in fact automatically going to happen with the `PerformanceGoal` setting of functions.  The default value of `$PerformanceGoal`, the value of which depends on relevant controls being active.  You can test this using

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1}, 
 Column[{Slider[Dynamic[a]], Dynamic[{a, $PerformanceGoal}]}]]
```