# Why does Manipulate execute the expression twice?

Tags: evaluation, manipulate

When I execute `Foobar[]` in the code below and move a slider, the variable `grad` is printed twice. Why is this? How can I make the `Manipulate` body only execute once on each update?

```
Foobar[] := Module[{f, vars, grad},
   f = a x^3 - b x^2 + c y^2;
   vars = {a, b, c};
   With[{fman = f, controls = Apply[Sequence, {{#, 0}, -5, 5} & /@ vars]},
    Manipulate[
     g = fman/(x^2 + y^2 + 1);
     grad = D[g, {{x, y}}];
     Print[grad];
     , controls]
    ]
   ];
```

**Edit:** As noticed below, this function is creating a `Manipulate`. My concern is why the `Manipulate` appears to be executing twice for every one update. This is a minimal working example and hence there is significant amount of code (that takes a while to run) excluded from inside the `Manipulate` body. I included `Print` to emphasize that the code appears to be executing twice.

Comment: you should put everything inside manipulate, like it is supposed to be. do not invent strange constructs and wonder why and what. waste of time to analyze as it is not the right way to do something.

Comment: @RobertH It looks like he's writing a function that will create a `Manipulate`.  There's nothing wrong with that.  I would expect that eventually `f` and `vars` will be passed in as arguments of `Foobar`.

Comment: By the way, this answer should help you: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8073/69

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you need is [`ContinuousAction -> False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContinuousAction.html) and [`TrackedSymbols -> vars`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrackedSymbols.html):

```
Foobar[] :=
  Module[{f, vars, grad}, f = a x^3 - b x^2 + c y^2;
   vars = {a, b, c};
   With[{fman = f, controls = Apply[Sequence, {{#, 0}, -5, 5} & /@ vars]},
    Manipulate[
     g = fman/(x^2 + y^2 + 1);
     grad = D[g, {{x, y}}];
     Print[grad];
     , controls, ContinuousAction -> False, TrackedSymbols -> vars]
   ]];
```

`ContinuousAction -> False` is needed to keep from evaluating continuously while dragging the sliders.  In the original version this happened and the `Print` statements were sent to the Messages window.

`TrackedSymbols -> vars` is needed to keep *Mathematica* from reevaluating when the values of `g` or `grad` change (which would be necessary if these were interdependent).

Comment: Interesting, this does seem to fix it. Why do you think a `Rule` is necessary for `TrackedSymbols` rather than a `RuleDelayed`?

Comment: @James presumably `Manipulate` checks to see that the value of `TrackedSymbols` is a list of Symbols, and `vars` is not expressly so.  If this is of considerable interest to you post it as a new question and I will dig deeper.