# There is an issue with Manipulate in which it updates its argument twice in V10

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, evaluation

I have asked this question before ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73489/resizing-or-moving-notebook-window-causes-manipulate-to-update-its-argument)) and I thought that the issue is only when moving the Notebook window.

It appears that Manipulate is working in weird manner.

```
data = RandomReal[100, {10000, 10}];
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{RandomReal[100]}, {ListPlot[data[[;; , i]], 
     PlotLabel -> RandomReal[100], ImageSize -> 400, 
     PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[1]]]}}], {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

Manipulate updates its argument twice even if the window is static without moving.

[image]

This is really creates a big problem for me and all codes done in V9 are very slow running in V10.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update:**

the suggested solution by Sjoerd C. de Vries works in this case but not in general as shown in this example:

```
Manipulate[
 a = Log[i];
 Grid[{{RandomReal[100]}, {ListPlot[a data[[;; , i]], 
     PlotLabel -> RandomReal[100], ImageSize -> 400, 
     PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[1]], 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]}}], {i, 2, 10, 1}]
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you check to see whether the links below and the answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46474/57) solve your problem?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it does for this particulate example. I have a long Manipualte argument with a lot of computations. please check the update.

Comment: For me, the same problem occurs in **both** V9 and V10 with OSX(10.9.5). Bug ??

Comment: Related: [(8072)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8072/121), [(8373)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8373/121)

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that this double evaluation is simply part of the mechanism of `Manipulate`.  When the slider is dragged one expression is displayed, and when it is released another is displayed.  I described this a bit in [PolarPlot render oddities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8072/121) but here is another example.  I use [`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlActive.html) to make the behavior explicit but same action is implicit without it.

```
Manipulate[ControlActive["foo", RandomReal[{0, i}]], {i, 2, 10, 1}]
```

Observe that while the slider is being dragged "foo" is displayed rather than a random number. When the slider is released the second expression is evaluated and displayed as a random number.  If you wish to avoid the second evaluation you can store a copy of the result of the first evaluation and display it at that time:

```
DynamicModule[{x},
  Manipulate[a = Log[i];
    ControlActive[
      x = Grid[{{RandomReal[100]},
           {ListPlot[a data[[;; , i]], PlotLabel -> RandomReal[100], 
            ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[1]]]}}],
      x
    ],
    {i, 2, 10, 1},
    TrackedSymbols :> {i}
  ]
]
```

*Edit: added `TrackedSymbols :> {i}` to improve evaluation behavior.*
See Michael's comment below for caveats.

---

### Update

The method above has problems with quick clicks on the slider.  This *seems* to solve the problem but I have only tested it briefly:

```
Manipulate[
  Block[{$ControlActiveSetting = False},
    a = Log[i];
    Grid[{{RandomReal[100]}, {ListPlot[a data[[;; , i]], PlotLabel -> RandomReal[100], 
      ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[1]]]}}]
  ],
  {i, 2, 10, 1}, 
  TrackedSymbols :> {i}
]
```

Comment: The assignment to `x` usually causes a subsequent update. Hitting the + button of the animator causes two updates. If the + button is hit several times quickly, the subsequent increments to `i` cause only one update.  If one waits the 3 sec. for `$ControlActiveSetting` to be set to `False`, then hitting the + button causes two updates. A quick click on the slider causes no recalculation of the `ListPlot` because `$ControlActiveSetting` never changes to `True`. Dragging the slider works as (I) expected. `TrackedSymbols` does not seem to solve all these issues. [I don't have a suggestion yet.]

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the notes and corrections. `TrackedSymbols :> {i}` at least seems to help so I added it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 With `TrackedSymbols` edit, two problems remain : 1/no recalculation of ListPlot when you quick click the slider (but dragging works), 2/ when you click on + or - button, the plot is now recalculated only once (as it should) but I notice that the bracket cell shows it evaluates once more (with no effect).

Comment: @SquareOne Yes, I knew that. That's what I meant that "`TrackedSymbols` does not seem to solve all these issues," but comments don't really give enough space for full explanations. I thought eventually I would solve the problem (or someone else would) but I failed to. It may be that `$ControlActiveSetting` is tracked by the FE instead of the kernel, and in any case, it is tracked no matter the setting of `TrackedSymbols`. (This is the reason for your second point.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Could you check my **Update**, please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it seems to work perfectly.  But I'm too tired to figure out why. Already gave a +1. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this is good solution and I already up-vote but unfortunately it did not work for my case because I have around 10 controls. I don't know if I can use TrackedSymbols or nor for such number of controls.

Comment: @Algohi Can you add a more complete example?  I will attempt to apply my method to it if I have time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I am really looking forward for your solution which I am sure it will be elegant. I am just very busy (these days) to give a complete example of what I am looking for. definitely the solution will be very important step toward full understanding how dynamic base functions works in MMA. I can send you my full code in case you are interested but it is fetching data from local database which means it will not work from your place. I will give more complete example soon.

Comment: @Algohi No problem.  Let me know when you are able to post that example here.  I get busy too so you make have to poke me a few times before I remember to answer. :^)

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit

This is the workaround I've found :

```
data = RandomReal[100, {10000, 10}];

Manipulate[
 Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality", a}, a = Log[i];
  Grid[{{RandomReal[100]}, {ListPlot[a data[[;; , i]], 
      PlotLabel -> RandomReal[100], ImageSize -> 400, 
      PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[1]], 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]}}]], {i, 2, 10, 1}]
```

`a` (which is a function of `i`) must be defined as a local value inside the `Block` and then set to its value.

It seems everything works as it should be (click and dragging the slider, click on buttons +/-)

---

#### Previous

As indicated the problem can be solved with the option **`$PerformanceGoal`**, but as the OP showed it is not enough here just to set the option inside **`ListPlot`**.

Let's take a simpler example :

```
Manipulate[i + 1; 
 ListPlot[RandomReal[10, 100], PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> $PerformanceGoal, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

As a label, i just display the `$PerformanceGoal` and it is clear that when you click the **+** button, the plot is displayed : the first time with `$PerformanceGoal` set to `"Speed"` and the second time set to `"Quality"`. Setting the option inside `ListPlot` seems to have no effect.

[image]

The problem is solved if you set `$PerformanceGoal` inside a **`Block`**. Here:

```
Manipulate[i + 1; 
 Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality"}, 
  ListPlot[RandomReal[10, 100], PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]]}, 
   PlotLabel -> $PerformanceGoal]], {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

#### Update

HOWEVER, this is not the end of the story, because as commented the OP, the previous solution won't work for the particular case at the end of his post. My example was too simple : there is no variable `i` inside the `ListPlot`.

Let's make something more complicated, just multiply the `RandomReal` list by `i` (inside `ListPlot`):

```
Manipulate[i + 1;
 Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality"}, 
  ListPlot[i*RandomReal[10, 10000], PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]]}, 
   PlotLabel -> $PerformanceGoal]], {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

You can check that will work too.

BUT if you set `a=i` then multiply `RandomReal` by `a`, now it won't work:
*(note that I added a `Pause` inside the `Block` in order to see better the evaluations, it does not modify the problem)*

```
Manipulate[i + 1; a = i;
 Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality"}, Pause[0.5];
  ListPlot[a*RandomReal[10, 20000], PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]]}, 
   PlotLabel -> $PerformanceGoal]], {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Note also that, though the `$PerformanceGoal` changes no more, you can clearly see that the code is evaluated twice, whether the slide is moved by clicking (not dragging), or the **+** or **-** buttons are clicked.

**unless you do:**

```
Manipulate[i + 1;
 Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Quality", a}, Pause[0.5];
  a = i; ListPlot[a*RandomReal[10, 20000], 
   PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]]}, 
   PlotLabel -> $PerformanceGoal]], {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

#### Other strange behaviours

I have played a little bit with all this, and I also observed some other strange behaviours :

You can even have three evaluations if you do that :

```
Manipulate[a = i; Pause[0.5]; 
 Grid[{{RandomReal[100]}, {ListPlot[a*RandomReal[10, 100], 
     PlotLabel -> RandomReal[100], ImageSize -> 400, 
     PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[1]]]}}], {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

or if you put the same code into two separate cells, just one beneath the over, and then if you change the position of one slider, this is what happens :

```
Manipulate[i + 1; a = i;
 ListPlot[a*RandomReal[10, 100], PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> $PerformanceGoal, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {i, 1,
   10, 1}]
```

and the same

```
Manipulate[i + 1; a = i;
 ListPlot[a*RandomReal[10, 100], PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> $PerformanceGoal, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {i, 1,
   10, 1}]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I tried to fit your solution to the second case in the question but it did not work.

Comment: @Algohi You are right ! :( I did not test your specific problem, and the `Block` does not help ! I'll edit my post to mention that, and will do some other tests ...

Comment: @Algohi Did my workaround helped you to solve the different problems you had ? Are there any other problems you noticed ?