# Plot using Manipulate or Animate

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PolarPlot render oddities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/polarplot-render-oddities)

When I use manipulate or animate function, the result shows a non-smooth plot. How to make the manipulate or animate commands show good and smooth plot?

Comment: Sounds like you want [`PerformanceGoal->"Quality"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PerformanceGoal.html)

Comment: You should provide an example where you get a "non-smooth" plot with `Manipulate`. As I understand your ecpectations you'd like to slow down the movement of the slider or/and locators in `Manipulate`, one can do it by pressing `Alt` while dragging the controls and  `Alt+Ctrl` for finer control.