# Animated 3D graphics is low resolution

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I'm trying to animate a 3D shape in **Mathematica 7**.  It's working, but the graphics is extremely crude while animated.  The resolution gets better if I stop the animation.  Is there a way to get a nice resolution while animated ?

Here's the code I'm currently using.  I'm sure it could be improved, but I don't know how.

```
omega = 1;
power[theta_, phi_, t_] = 
  1/32 (35 + 28 Cos[2 theta] + Cos[4 theta] - 
     8 Cos[4 (phi + omega t)] Sin[theta]^4);

Animate[ParametricPlot3D[
  power[theta, phi, t] {Sin[theta] Cos[phi], Sin[theta] Sin[phi], 
    Cos[theta]}, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 500, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, 
  Ticks -> None, AxesStyle -> RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 1], 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

In case you're curious, this is the gravitational radiation power radiated away from a rotating ellipsoid.

Comment: Related [question and answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/polarplot-render-oddities).