# Why wrapping this ContourPlot inside a Manipulate changes its output into something unrecognizable?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am a bit puzzled: I wrap the same exact ContoutPlot inside a Manipulate, and it looks all wrong (I don't know what it's drawing but it does not look like the zeros of my polynomial).
What am I doing wrong, and how can I correctly wrap my plot inside a Manipulate so that I can later on put a Locator on it that will give me the correct {p,q} values?

```
myPoly := -4 p^3 - 27 q^2;
PrintPoly[poly_] := ContourPlot[poly == 0, {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}];
ManiPoly[poly_] := Manipulate[
                       ContourPlot[poly == 0, {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}],   
                       {point, {1, 1}}
                   ];
ManiPoly[myPoly]
PrintPoly[myPoly]
```

The funny thing about is that when I first open the notebook, they look the same, but when I *actually* evaluate the cell, they look like in the attached screenshot (this is a fresh instance of Mathematica 10.0 with no other instances running):

[image]

Comment: They look the same to me on 10.0.1.0. Maybe post a screen shot of the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screen capture appears to show the `ContourPlot` frozen in `"Speed"` mode:

```
myPoly := -4 p^3 - 27 q^2;

ContourPlot[myPoly == 0, {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

Normally this should only appear while the controls are being used, after which it should switch to `"Quality"` mode.  See:

- [PolarPlot render oddities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8072/121)

I do not see this problem on my system running 10.0.2.  I propose setting `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` explicitly:

```
ManiPoly[poly_] := 
 Manipulate[ContourPlot[poly == 0, {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {point, {1, 1}}]
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. I spent a couple of hours on this without figuring it out.

Comment: @Tobia Glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.