# switch between automatic and manual updating

Tags: plotting, dynamic, gui-construction, scheduling

I have a plot with interactive controls. I'd like to give the user the option between having the plot automatically update (when the plot's parameters are changed with the slider) and having the update happen only when an 'update' button is pushed. I've been spinning my wheels on this for a long time. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a simple example.

Comment: By the way you might want to look at [`ContinuousAction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuousAction.html) if you have not done so already.  It is not an answer to your question but it can provide a reasonable in-between in some cases.

Comment: And if performance is an issue then `ControlActive` is good to know.

Comment: @Kuba Good point!  nibudd, please see [(8072)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8072/121) for one example, or search the site for others

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Edit

> Can you think of another way to accomplish the same thing [...]? It would be nice to have a solution that didn't involve duplicating each slider.
>
> -nibudd

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, tempA = 1, auto = True}
 ,
 ifAuto = Dynamic[
     If[auto, Identity, Setting]@#, 
     TrackedSymbols :> {auto}
 ] &;
 
 Column[{
   ifAuto @ Dynamic @ Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 1}],
   Slider[Dynamic[a], {1, 10}],
   Checkbox[Dynamic[auto]],
   Button["Update", auto = True; FinishDynamic[]; auto = False;, 
    Method -> "Queued", Enabled -> Dynamic@Not@auto]
   }]
 ]
```

- `ifAuto` function is meant to be used on `Dynamic` parts of GUI that you want to be affected by this behaviour.
- `ifAuto's` `Dynamic` output  is triggered only when variable `auto` changes
- If `auto === True` then it acts as it wasn't there. E.g `Dynamic[Plot[...]...]` is shown and the *FrontEnd* will take care about its updates according to what was set there.

  `If[` from `ifauto` is only run when `auto` changes so it does not affect the performance, neat. Read more in [tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality/Nesting Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html)
- If `auto === False` then `Setting @ Dynamic @ Plot[...` is shown, effectively stripping `Dynamics` and leaving `Plot[...` which won't be updated by `a's` changes (because of the very outer `TrackedSymbols:>{auto}`.

---

#### Initial approach

The idea is to switch controllers between main `a` variable and a temporary one `tempA's`.

The `Checkbox` toggles that. It also makes both variables synchronized so that the transistion is "smooth".

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, tempA = 1, auto = True},
 Column[{
   Dynamic @ Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 1}],
   PaneSelector[
    {
     True -> Slider[Dynamic[a], {1, 10}],
     False -> Slider[Dynamic[tempA], {1, 10}]
     },
    Dynamic@auto
    ],
   Checkbox[Dynamic[auto, If[auto = #, a = tempA, tempA = a] &]],
   Button["Update", a = tempA, Enabled -> Dynamic@Not@auto]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Instead of `PaneSelector` you can use

```
`Slider[Dynamic[tempA, (tempA = #; If[auto, a = tempA]) &], {1, 10}]`
```

but spamming `If` whenever you move a `Slider` is not neat.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was trying to achieve. Now to understand what you've done here - thank you!

Comment: If you'll indulge me, I have some questions about how this works: 
1. What is the `If` pure function taking as its argument, the value of `Checkbox`?

2. What is the meaning of `auto = #` in the first argument of `If`? Is `#` being evaluated to determine which expression to execute (`a = tempA` or `tempA = a`) and then assigning that value to `auto`?

2b. If so, why is that necessary? Isn't auto already tied to the Checkbox?

3. What is the meaning of `@` here? I can't find any documentation on this kind of usage (`Dynamic @ Plot[...`, `Dynamic @ auto`, or `Dynamic @ Not @ auto`)

Comment: @nibudd 1. take a look at docs for `Dynamic`, the second argument of `Dynamic` can be a function which does whatever you want with the state of the controller. `#` is a slot which will be filled with that state, so True or False. 2. `auto = #` has 2 roles, assigns `Checkbox` state to `auto` and returns this value so we can synchronize `a` with `tempA` (when `a` or `tempA` is active the other isn't though we don't want it's old value to pop up after switching). Hope that was clear. About `@`, take a look at [What the @#%^&*?!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478)

Comment: I did read the documentation on `Dynamic`, but since I'm relatively new to Mathematica, I did not find it terribly helpful. I appreciate you clearing up my confusion. Can you think of another way to accomplish the same thing by using the TrackedSymbols attribute of Plot? I've been trying to do this with something like `TrackedSymbols :> 
 Dynamic[list, If[manualUpdate = #, list = {update}, list = {a, b}] &]' where `update` is tied to my update button, and `a, b` are tied to two different sliders.  It would be nice to have a solution that didn't involve duplicating each slider.

Comment: @nibudd I see, take a look at the edit, that should be it.

Comment: So `Setting` causes `TrackedSymbolx:>{auto}` to be applied to `Dynamic@Plot[...` but `Identity` does not? Why is that?

Comment: @nibudd I don't understand, I said what `Setting` does and documentation also says so, it strips `Dynamic` inner to `Setting`. That is all.