# call function to trigger update to dynamic -- what's the right way

Tags: programming, dynamic, evaluation, scoping, scheduling

I want to create a plot using `Dynamic`. Ideally, I'd have some persistent, locally scoped state variables living in a `Module`; as these variables are updated the plot should change.

I've tried defining a function within the `Module` scope: calling this function updates the state variables. From the `Module`, I return both the plot object and the function. Both can be passed around wherever I need them, but calling the function from anywhere needs to always update the plot.

```
ClearAll[callback, plot];
{callback, plot} = Module[{plot, callfunc, currPath, currT0, currT1},
   currPath = Function[{t}, 0.0];
   currT0 = 0.0;
   currT1 = 1.0;
   plot = Dynamic[Plot[currPath[t], {t, currT0, currT1}]];
   callfunc = Function[{pp, t0, a, t1, b}, (
      currPath = pp;
      currT0 = t0;
      currT1 = t1;
      )];
   {callfunc, plot}];
```

Here's what I've got so far. This works when calling the function directly in the frontend but not in other circumstances, and also there are red-highlighted warning texts everywhere. Perhaps I should be using `DynamicModule`, but in that case I can't return values from it in the same straightforward way (it doesn't just return the 2-element list, it includes lots of other stuff too).

What's the right way for me to do this?

Edit:

I think I have this working now.

```
Do[callback[4*#&, 0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],{i,5}]
```

worked as expected. However,

```
Do[callback[i*#&, 0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],{i,5}]
```

failed. This was a scoping issue. The fix is:

```
Do[callback[Module[{ii=i},ii*#&], 0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],{i,5}]
```

On the other hand, the frontend still gives me glaring red warnings in this code, which suggests I'm doing something wrong. Can someone explain this?

Comment: It seems to work for me.  What exactly are the "other circumstances"?

Comment: Passing callback around to other functions, calling it inside other scopes, etc.

Comment: @MichaelCurry see the second point in my answer: [138404](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138404/5478). Please add some usage examples/cases.

Comment: @MichaelCurry That's what I tried. As Kuba asks, some examples where it fails are needed.

Comment: The problem here is that you're trying to localize the variables with `Module`, but `Module` does not give you persistently scoped symbols: it implements lexical scoping, meaning that the variable are only localized to the bit of code you put inside of the `Module`. When you use `callback` outside of the `Module` the localization is gone. The fact that is works at all should be more surprising than that is sometimes fails. What you probably want here, are variables that live in a different context. Read the documentation for `Begin` and see if that does what you need.

Comment: The issue with `Do[callback[i*# &, 0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],{i,5}]` is usually addressed by `Do[callback[With[{i = i}, i*# &], 0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],{i,5}]` to get around the `HoldAll` attribute of `Function` (`&`).  See the documentation for `With`, under "Scope".

Comment: `Module` "localizes" variables by add a $ plus a serial number to the symbol name; what you get is in fact a symbol in the ``Global` `` context that should be unique. It is also given the `Temporary` attribute, which means that when all references to it are gone, it may be garbage-collected and removed.  As long as your ``Global` `` `callback` and `plot` are around and you don't accidentally use a variable with the same symbol name as your `Module` variables, things should work. You can avoid clashing with `Module` variables by not ending your variable names with a $ plus a number.

Comment: ...In other words, I disagree with @SjoerdSmit's assertion that "outside of the `Module` the localization is gone." The localization is given by the unique symbol name, and that is still around outside the `Module`.  Just examine the definitions `? callback` and `? plot`, and evaluate the `Module` variables found in it.

Comment: But if your goal is to obtain unique variables starting with a $ symbol, then you might as well use `Unique` which is designed specifically for such applications. The fact that `Module` generates `Temporary` symbols should tell you that it's not meant for generating persistent symbols and that you can get in trouble when you do. If you want to have persistent symbols that do not clash, it's much better practise to give them their own context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `Do` loop problem is not related to the main issue here. As pointed out, use `With[{i=i},...` or something. See more in:

- [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478)

To the point now:

The rule of thumb is not to use `Module` variables inside `Dynamic`, see:

- [John Fultz answer on math group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcLM5xDRqHE/V0FghIKeO_QJ)

It is not banned though and can be useful as long as you know what do you do, why and what consequences it has.

And the fundamental problem is that your scoped e.g. `currT0` -> `currT0$100` is guaranteed to be unique only within current kernel session.

See the second point in:

- [Can a Dynamic be attached to the single elements of a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138404/5478)

But if the gui is not suppose to be around across different sessions, you should be fine.

> What's the right way for me to do this?

- [Absolute control over updates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2862/5478)
- [Working with Dynamic: Synchronization with EventActions ( and other preemptive evaluations)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120397/5478)

So shortly, within `DynamicModule`, FE takes care about making its variables local. But they change their names in each session, this is why your code needs to be executed in `Initialization`.

Here's a small example that may address your problem more precisely:

```
ClearAll[call, plot];

plot = DynamicModule[{a = 1, t1 = 0.0, t2 = 0.1}
  , Dynamic[Plot[a t, {t, t1, t2}]]
  , Initialization :> (call = Function[{values}, {a, t1, t2} = values] )
];
```

But notice that `call` is not assigned till `plot` "instance" is displayed. So show it:

```
plot
```

and run, e.g. `call[{2, 0, 2}]`.

Comment: Thanks! The Initialization option seems to make DynamicModule do what I want. There are still some scoping subtleties to figure out here, but that option is key and now I can persist my plots across sessions.